# Error con variable no definida python

Tags: python, variables, pycharm

Estoy haciendo un programa para insertar paquetes en un sistema. A la hora de ingresar el valor de la variable `envio` alega `Name can be undefined`

La variable `envio` almacena en forma de carácter la palabra "Aéreo" o "Marítimo" según se haya escogido en un `while` anteriormente.

**Código con el error de variable potencialmente indefinida**

```
if opcion == 1:
    os.system("cls")
    print("*****Ingresar un nuevo paquete****")
    id = input("Ingrese el Id del paquete: ")
    nombres = input("Ingrese El o Los Nombres:")
    apellidos = input("Ingrese Los Apellidos: ")
    descripcion = input("Ingrese una descripcion del paquete:")
    peso = int(input("Ingrese el peso del paquete en libras"))
    tipo_de_envio = ""

    while tipo_de_envio not in ["a", "m"]:
        tipo_de_envio = input("Ingrese el tipo de envio [A]o [M]".lower())

    if tipo_de_envio == "a":
        envio = "Aereo"
        tarifa = 9
        coste = peso * tarifa
    elif tipo_de_envio == "m":
        envio = "Marítimo"
        tarifa = 3
        coste = peso * tarifa

    conf_paquete = ""
    while conf_paquete not in ["s","n"]:
        conf_paquete = input("el tipo de envio es: {}".format(envio))
```

Por cierto, si yo pongo que se imprima en pantalla la variable `envio` debajo de los casos de la variable `coste` este problema no aparece.

Estoy trabajando desde Pycharm pero quise ejecutarlo desde línea de comandos y me presento el error de variable potencialmente no definida (en Pycharm con emulación de la terminal si funciona, ojo).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El problema con el código es que no todos los caminos de ejecución definen la variable `envio`.

```
if tipo_de_envio == "a":
    envio = "Aereo"
    tarifa = 9
    coste = peso * tarifa
elif tipo_de_envio == "m":
    envio = "Marítimo"
    tarifa = 3
    coste = peso * tarifa
```

Según Python, si `tipo_de_envio` es distinto de "a" y "m", la variable `envio` no se inicializa.

Para ti está claro que `tipo_de_envio` **sólo** puede ser "a" o "m", pero para Python no. Por eso te acusa un potencial problema (no es un error, pero podría serlo).

La solución en este caso es cambiar el `elif` por un `else`, ya que garantiza que las variables `envio, tarifa y coste` serán siempre inicializadas, sin importar si el `if` resulta `True` o `False`:

```
if tipo_de_envio == "a":
    envio = "Aereo"
    tarifa = 9
    coste = peso * tarifa
else:
    envio = "Marítimo"
    tarifa = 3
    coste = peso * tarifa
```